# Identifying Min and Max Prices within a Time Range

Tags: time, pine-script, pine-script-v5, price

I'm currently working on a Pine Script strategy. I need assistance in calculating the minimum and maximum prices within a specific time range, let's say between 12:00 and 14:00 every day. I started the code below.

Now I want to pull the maximum (minimum) value of rangeHigh (rangeLow) and plot it on the chart for entire tsession period.

```
//@version=5
strategy("minimum and maximum prices within a specific time range", overlay = true)
//Variables
topening= time(timeframe.period,”1200-1300:1234567")
tsession = time(timeframe.period,"1300-1600:1234567")
tbis = time(timeframe.period,”1200-1400:1234567")
cond_tbis = not na(tbis)
// Calculate Price Range between 12:00 and 14:00
rangeHigh = (cond_tbis ? request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", high)[topening] : 0) 
rangeLow = (cond_tbis ? request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", low)[topening] : 70000)
```