# Indicator that plots range of price of a certain time window

Tags: pine-script, technical-indicator

I'm currently working on coding an indicator that can display the price range within which an asset has been fluctuating during a specific time window each day. For example, I want to identify the range between 8 am and 9 am and plot it on a chart. Additionally, I'd like to visualize this range between 9 am and 12 pm, similar to the screenshot provided.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this task more effectively?

[image]

I tried this code but it failed

```
//Variables
topening= time(timeframe.period,"0800-0900:1234567")
tsession = time(timeframe.period,"0900-1200:1234567")
cond_topening= not na(topening)
cond_tsession= not na(tsession)
// Calculate Price Range
rangeHigh = (cond_topening ? request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", high)[topening] : na)
rangeLow = (time_cond_topening ? request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", low)[topening] : na)

// Plot time and Price Range
plot(rangeHigh, color = color.blue, linewidth = 4)
plot(rangeLow, color = color.blue, linewidth = 4)
bgcolor( time_cond_topening ? color.blue : time_cond_tsession ? color.green : na)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying Min and Max Prices within a Time Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76351578/identifying-min-and-max-prices-within-a-time-range)